# How to create a voice recording app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create a voice recording app in Flutter.Can someone explain which package to be used and explain how to implement that package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check thi library [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound#-installing-tab-)

This plugin provides simple recorder and player functionalities.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the 3 best options:

1. flutter_sound
2. flutter_sound_lite (a lite version of above with some fewer codecs available)
3. flauto ( build on top of flutter_sound with lock screen support )